# The support of a measure vs. the support of the conditional measures

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are complete separable metric spaces, and let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $X\times Y$. Let $S$ be the support of $\mu$, i.e.,
$$
S=\{(x,y)\in X\times Y:\mu(V)>0\text{ for all nonempty }V\text{ open in }X\times Y\text{ containing }(x,y)\}.
$$
Is the following true? There is a version of the regular conditional probability measure $\mu(\cdot|x)$ such that for each $x$ in the projection of $S$ on $X$, the set
$$
\{y\in Y:(x,y)\in S\}
$$
is precisely the support of $\mu(\cdot|x)$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true in general, I think, here is one attempt to show that. Let $X\times Y=[0,1]^2$. For $x\in[0,1)$, let $\mu(\cdot|x)$ be the (normalized) Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ (restricted to the Borel sigma-algebra). For $x=1$, let $\mu(\cdot|x)$ be the (normalized) Lebesgue measure on $[0,1/2]$ (restricted to the Borel sigma-algebra). Let $\mu$ be a Borel measure on $[0,1]^2$ defined by $\mu(A)=\int\mu(A_x|x)\nu(dx)$ for some nonatomic Borel measure on $[0,1]$ with support $[0,1]$, where $A_x$ is the $x$-section of $A$ in $[0,1]$. The support of $\mu$ is $[0,1]^2$ and yet the support of $\mu(\cdot|x=1)$ is $[0,1/2]$.